# Python 2.7 - Unable to correctly decode email subject-header line

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, decode, string-decoding

I'm using Python 2.7, and I am trying to properly decode the subject header line of an email. The source of the email is:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VGkgw6ggcGlhY2l1dGEgbGEgZGVtbz8gU2NvcHJpIGFsdHJlIG4=?=
```

I use the function decode_header(header) from the email.header library, and the result is:

```
[('Ti \xc3\xa8 piaciuta la demo? Scopri altre n', 'utf-8')]
```

The 'xc3\xa8' part should match the 'è' character, but it is not correctly decoded/showed.
Another example:

```
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?niccol=F2_cop?= =?iso-8859-1?Q?ernico?=
```

Result:

```
[('niccol\xf2 copernico', 'iso-8859-1')]
```

How can I obtain the correct string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* getting the correct string.  It's just encoded (using UTF-8 in the first case, and iso-8895-1 in the second); you need to decode it to get the actual unicode string.

For example:

```
>>> print unicode('Ti \xc3\xa8 piaciuta la demo? Scopri altre n', 'utf-8')
Ti è piaciuta la demo? Scopri altre n
```

Or:

```
>>> print unicode('niccol\xf2 copernico', 'iso-8859-1')
niccolò copernico
```

That's why you get back both the header data *and* the encoding.